# How to track why community changes have been undone

Tags: community, deployment, lightning-community, versioning

My team has reported several times regarding their community changes have been overwritten (Changes which are there once but disappear after a certain period of time).

Originally they though it was deployment issues. But I clearly showed to them by checking deployment status > deployment history, there is no deployment happening during that period of time.

It seems to me there is no way to track changes for community itself. So I am wondering is it possible for me to investigate the possible cause of this?

I have tried the scenario where two developers working on the same page and save at different times. But it seems to me that Salesforce handled this scenario really well. I can't find a single scenario where this should happen.

How may I investigate this one?

Comment: Maybe your users directly update communities from the setup of your production org ?
You may check for user connection logs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit hidden, but you can see this by doing the following:

1. Go to your Community's **Workspace**
2. Click on **Administration**
3. **Pages** *(on the left sidebar)*
4. **Go to Site.com Studio**
5. **Change History** *(on the left sidebar)*

[image]

---

[image]

---

You should see a list of versions with the following columns

- Version#
- Description
- Published Date
- Published By

You can click on the gear that pops up on each row when you hover over it with your mouse and select **View Details**